# Trigger a Step Function from SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-step-functions

I want to execute my step function when an SNS message is published and consume it. What's the best solution for this?

I know that one option is using a Lambda, subscribe to the SNS topic, and then trigger the SF from inside the Lambda....I was wondering if there's any (simpler) solution without this intermediate step.

Comment: I think lambda is best choice.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately not SNS.   You can [invoke a StepFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-invoke-sfn.html) from:

- Lambda
- API Gateway
- EventBridge
- CodePipeline
- IoT Rules Engine
- (other) Step Functions